# Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp)

Tags: php, xampp

To com um erro em dos session_start(), apareceu quando reinstalei o xampp.

Erro:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp) in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\libraries\joomla\session\handler\native.php on line 260
>   Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

native.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Platform
 * @subpackage  Session
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 */

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

/**
 * Interface for managing HTTP sessions
 *
 * @since       3.5
 * @deprecated  4.0  The CMS' Session classes will be replaced with the `joomla/session` package
 */
class JSessionHandlerNative implements JSessionHandlerInterface
{
 /**
  * Has the session been started
  *
  * @var    boolean
  * @since  3.5
  */
 private $started = false;

 /**
  * Has the session been closed
  *
  * @var    boolean
  * @since  3.5
  */
 private $closed = false;

 /**
  * Starts the session
  *
  * @return  boolean  True if started
  *
  * @since   3.5
  */
 public function start()
 {
  if ($this->isStarted())
  {
   return true;
  }

  $this->doSessionStart();

  return true;
 }

 /**
  * Checks if the session is started.
  *
  * @return  boolean  True if started, false otherwise.
  *
  * @since   3.5
  */
 public function isStarted()
 {
  return $this->started;
 }

 /**
  * Returns the session ID
  *
  * @return  string  The session ID
  *
  * @since   3.5
  */
 public function getId()
 {
  return session_id();
 }

 /**
  * Sets the session ID
  *
  * @param   string  $id  The session ID
  *
  * @return  void
  *
  * @since   3.5
  * @throws  LogicException
  */
 public function setId($id)
 {
  if ($this->isStarted())
  {
   throw new LogicException('Cannot change the ID of an active session');
  }

  session_id($id);
 }

 /**
  * Returns the session name
  *
  * @return  mixed  The session name
  *
  * @since   3.5
  */
 public function getName()
 {
  return session_name();
 }

 /**
  * Sets the session name
  *
  * @param   string  $name  The name of the session
  *
  * @return  void
  *
  * @since   3.5
  * @throws  LogicException
  */
 public function setName($name)
 {
  if ($this->isStarted())
  {
   throw new LogicException('Cannot change the name of an active session');
  }

  session_name($name);
 }

 /**
  * Regenerates ID that represents this storage.
  *
  * Note regenerate+destroy should not clear the session data in memory only delete the session data from persistent storage.
  *
  * @param   boolean  $destroy   Destroy session when regenerating?
  * @param   integer  $lifetime  Sets the cookie lifetime for the session cookie. A null value will leave the system settings unchanged,
  *                              0 sets the cookie to expire with browser session. Time is in seconds, and is not a Unix timestamp.
  *
  * @return  boolean  True if session regenerated, false if error
  *
  * @since   3.5
  */
 public function regenerate($destroy = false, $lifetime = null)
 {
  if (!headers_sent() && null !== $lifetime)
  {
   ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $lifetime);
  }

  $return = session_regenerate_id($destroy);

  // Workaround for https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61470 as suggested by David Grudl
  session_write_close();
  $this->closed = true;

  if (isset($_SESSION))
  {
   $backup = $_SESSION;
   $this->doSessionStart();
   $_SESSION = $backup;
  }
  else
  {
   $this->doSessionStart();
  }

  return $return;
 }

 /**
  * Force the session to be saved and closed.
  *
  * This method must invoke session_write_close() unless this interface is used for a storage object design for unit or functional testing where
  * a real PHP session would interfere with testing, in which case it should actually persist the session data if required.
  *
  * @return  void
  *
  * @see     session_write_close()
  * @since   3.5
  */
 public function save()
 {
  // Verify if the session is active
  if ((version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', 'ge') && PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE === session_status())
   || (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', 'lt') && $this->started && isset($_SESSION) && $this->getId()))
  {
   $session = JFactory::getSession();
   $data    = $session->getData();

   // Before storing it, let's serialize and encode the Registry object
   $_SESSION['joomla'] = base64_encode(serialize($data));

   session_write_close();

   $this->closed  = true;
   $this->started = false;
  }
 }

 /**
  * Clear all session data in memory.
  *
  * @return  void
  *
  * @since   3.5
  */
 public function clear()
 {
  // Need to destroy any existing sessions started with session.auto_start
  if ($this->getId())
  {
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
  }

  $this->closed  = true;
  $this->started = false;
 }

 /**
  * Performs the session start mechanism
  *
  * @return  void
  *
  * @since   3.5.1
  * @throws  RuntimeException If something goes wrong starting the session.
  */
 private function doSessionStart()
 {
  // Register our function as shutdown method, so we can manipulate it
  register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'save'));

  // Disable the cache limiter
  session_cache_limiter('none');

  /*
   * Extended checks to determine if the session has already been started
   */

  // If running PHP 5.4, try to use the native API
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', 'ge') && PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE === session_status())
  {
   throw new RuntimeException('Failed to start the session: already started by PHP.');
  }

  // Fallback check for PHP 5.3
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', 'lt') && !$this->closed && isset($_SESSION) && $this->getId())
  {
   throw new RuntimeException('Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set).');
  }

  // If we are using cookies (default true) and headers have already been started (early output),
  if (ini_get('session.use_cookies') && headers_sent($file, $line))
  {
   throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "%s" at line %d.', $file, $line));
  }

  // Ok to try and start the session
  if (!session_start())
  {
   throw new RuntimeException('Failed to start the session');
  }

  // Mark ourselves as started
  $this->started = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Você trocou a versão do PHP quando reinstalou o XAMPP?

Comment: Falta permissão de acesso/escrita nessa pasta